# How to distinguish between passive and past

Tags: passive-voice

> 1. This software calculates the amount of heat generated by a CPU.
> 2. This software calculates the amount of heat to be generated by a CPU.
> 3. This software calculates the amount of heat that a CPU will generate.

Is there a difference among three sentences listed above ?  Specifically, I would like to know whether the first one means the past.

Comment: Passive and past are not at the same level: Present and Past, Active and Passive. I eat apples [active]//Apples are eaten by me. [passive] 2 and 3 are about the future. 1 is in the present. There is no passive verb in any of them. generated by a CPU is an adjectival phrase.

Comment: By default, the passive #1 is interpreted as being "timeless" (it's irrelevant whether it's talking about heat that *was, is,* or *will be* generated, since the value doesn't change). To force the "past" interpretation you'd need something like *the amount of heat **which was** generated...* You second and third versions are both relatively unlikely, unless you specifically want to imply that the CPU hasn't *yet* generated any heat (because it's still at the design stage, perhaps).

Comment: #1 and #2 contain the passive verb phrases "generated by a CPU" and "to be generated by a CPU" (note the agentive _by_ phrases), both of which modify "heat".  I agree with FF, especially about #2 which might well be written as "the amount of heat _likely_ to be generated ...".

Comment: Also, if you want a sentence about heat that had been generated in the past, you need to say, "This software calculates the amount of heat that had been generated by a CPU." It's the past perfect that makes it about the past, not whether or not its passive voice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This software calculates the amount of heat generated by a CPU.**

OP asks:

> I would like to know whether [that sentence refers to] the past.

The verb **generated** there does *not* refer to a particular CPU which, at some time in the past, generated some heat.

Rather we have a past-participle form of the verb "generate" used adjectivally in conjunction with the indefinite article, **a**, to refer to typical behavior, that is, the heat any CPU generates.

... generated by a CPU.

Compare:

> How much water **is drunk** by an adult elephant each day?
>
> In his lecture, the naturalist mentioned the amount of water ***drunk* by an adult elephant** each day.